# sed: how to add text to first x occurrences

Tags: sed

I am trying to add text to the end of a line the first x times it occurs.  I know how to do it globally and for the n occurrence.  I can't figure out how to do it for the first nth occurrences.  An example would be a text.txt file that contains:

```
This is a test
junk
This is a test
More junk
This is a test
This is a test
This is a test
```

And, I want to add a '.' at the end of the first three times that "This is a test" occurs.  The output I am trying to get is:

```
This is a test.
junk
This is a test.
More junk
This is a test.
This is a test
This is a test
```

Comment: @Quasimodo I modified the question to further clarify what I am trying to do.  And, you are correct.  My work around doesn't do what I thought it did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`This.*test` is the correct regex. The asterisk means "0 or more times the previous character" so `This*test` wouldn't match any of your lines.

Now, Sed is bad at Arithmetics. For something elegant I suggest Awk:

```
awk '/This.*test/{c++};{print $0 (c<4 ? "." : "")}' file
```

I think it suffices to say that `c`, as any unset variable in Awk, is treated as zero, but let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: Note that your regular expression would also match `Don't dot this: This is not a test`.

Comment: @they That is a feature, not a bug.  The actual file I am trying to do this on has a fixed beginning and end; but, the stuff in the middle will change.

Answer (score 4):

Another variant that avoids doing the regexp matching after all 3 occurrences have already been found:

```
awk -v n=3 'n && /This is a test/ {n--; $0 = $0 "."}; {print}'
```

With `sed` specifically, you could do something like:

```
sed '
  1 {
    x
    s/^/.../
    x
  }
  /This is a test/ {
    s/$/./
    x
    s/.//
    /./ {
      x
      b
    }
    g
    :1
    $! {
      n
      b 1
    }
  }'
```

Where we track the number of `.`s to append as corresponding number of `.`s in the hold space.

It goes without saying that `sed` is a lot less appropriate for this kind of task. If the reason for wanting `sed` is for the `-i` extension for in-place editing found on a few implementations (borrowed from `perl`), note that the GNU implementation of `awk` can also do it with `-i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk`¹, or you could use the real thing:

```
perl -lpi -e '
  if ($n < 3 && /This is a test/) {
    $n++;
    $_ .= ".";
  }' your-file
```

If you wanted to add a `.` after each occurrence of `This is a test` as opposed to all lines that contain at least one occurrence of `This is a test`, `perl` would also be the best choice:

```
perl -pi -e 's{This is a test\K}{$n++ < 3 ? "." : ""}ge' your-file
```

---

<sup>¹ **do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

With `perl` we could do as shown

```
perl -lpe '
  $_ = $k == 3 ? next : s/This is a test(?{$k++}).*\K/./r;
' file
```

---

Elephants can dance too, albeit the simple steps.
Using `GNU sed` writing in its extended regex mode `-E`  we can store the count as number of newlines in the hold.

```
K=3
sed -Ee '
  /This is a test/!b
  G
  /(.*\n){'"$K"'}.*\n/!{
    s/\n+/./p;z;H;d
  }
  s/\n+//
  :a;n;ba
' file
```